# Cell rendering with FX in JTable

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Given a renderer implemented in JavaFX that renders something onto a Canvas. It works well.
This renderer needs to be usable in Swing applications and it works fine thanks to JFXPanel component in most of the use cases, except for JTable. If the user wants render table cell values with the given renderer, the application starts to fail in many different ways.

Here's a sample application:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.IOException;    
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class TableRenderer {

    private JFrame frame;

    private JFrame createFrame(String title, JComponent component, int width, int height) {
        final Dimension dimension = new Dimension(width, height);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(Util.getActiveScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        frame.setSize(dimension);
        frame.add(component);
        frame.setTitle(title);

        Util.center(frame);
        frame.pack();

        return frame;
    }

    private void show() {
        try {
            init();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() throws IOException {

        JTable table = new JTable(new TableModel());
        table.setRowHeight(200);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CellRenderer());
        JScrollPane p = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        frame = createFrame("Renderer Demo - JTable", p, 420, 220);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TableRenderer app = new TableRenderer();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(app::show);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return "this is cell at ("+columnIndex+"; "+rowIndex+")";
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    };

    private static class CellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            Rectangle cellRect = table.getCellRect(row, column, true);
            Renderer renderer = new Renderer(cellRect.getSize(), value);
            renderer.setSize(cellRect.getSize());
            renderer.setPreferredSize(cellRect.getSize());
            renderer.setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
            return renderer;
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class Renderer extends JFXPanel {

        public Renderer(Dimension cellRect, Object value) {
            super();
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cellRect.getWidth(), cellRect.getHeight());
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.RED);
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillText(value.toString(), 10, 10);
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(10, 10, 10, 10);
            root.getChildren().add(canvas);
            setScene(scene);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case nothing appears in the cells and the application freezes.

The same thing works just fine if displayed in JPanel

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class PanelRenderer {
    private JFrame frame;

    private JFrame createFrame(String title, JComponent component, int width, int height) {
        final Dimension dimension = new Dimension(width, height);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        frame.setSize(dimension);
        frame.add(component);
        frame.setTitle(title);

        Util.center(frame);
        frame.pack();

        return frame;
    }

    private void show() {
        try {
            init();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() throws IOException {


        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new Renderer(new Dimension(200, 200), "Demo"));

        frame = createFrame("Renderer Demo - JPanel", p, 200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PanelRenderer app = new PanelRenderer();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(app::show);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class Renderer extends JFXPanel {

        public Renderer(Dimension cellRect, Object value) {
            super();
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cellRect.getWidth(), cellRect.getHeight());
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.RED);
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillText(value.toString(), 10, 10);
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(10, 10, 10, 10);
            root.getChildren().add(canvas);
            setScene(scene);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to add the renderer in a JPanel and return that as a cell renderer component, no change.

I've tried to synchronize FXThread and EDT, it is a hell and nothing happens.

I've tried to render an image, create a Component, overwrite the paintComponent to draw image, and synchronize the threads. That seems to work on Windows, but on OSX still fails.

I'm doing something wrong, or I should accept that this usecase is from the devil and no way to make it work?

Comment: A cell renderer actually is intended to be reused for every cell (optimization, not creating say a new JLabel for every table cell). I would first do that, having a "floating" component repainting every cell. And then the JavaFX bridge.

Comment: That works for pure Swing. But I have no idea how to synchronize it if the FX Thread comes in. Every attempt I've made caused a mix of the table cells or a deadlock.